# Use Report Object Inside OpenERP Webkit Report Header

Tags: webkit, report, odoo, wkhtmltopdf, openerp-7

I'm creating an invoice report for OpenERP 7 using webkit engine

I need to display the invoice number and the partner in the header.

I've tried using the variable directly:

```
${inv.partner_id.name}
```

but it's giving me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Undefined' object has no attribute 'partner_id'
```

is there any workaround for this problem ?

it's possible to use the inv variable directly in RML

but I can't use RML for this report for some reason.

thanks before

Answer (score 0):

Solved it,
I can just use:

```
%for inv in objects :
```

Comment: Can you add some more context so that your answer could also be useful for other people?